# HP Microserver and upgrade from Ubuntu 12 to 16

Tags: upgrade, hp

I was running Ubuntu LTS 12 on an HP Proliant Micrserver Gen8 since 4 years.
Last week I decided to upgrade (upgrade in-place, not a new and fresh install) from 12 to 14, then to 16, according to the best practice provided by the official documentation.
Everything keeps working with no issue, but... after the upgrade I notice (and everyone here) an increased noise level of the Microserver.
Looking at the server hardware by the HP iLO, I can see that the speed of the fan is increased and there is no apparently reason for that.
We are during the winter here and the ambient temperature is quite low.
The server is used just for file sharing with SAMBA, nothing else so... the CPU load is ZERO when no files are being transferred.

Do you have any suggestions?

Power Settings of the Microserver are set to "OS Control Mode", means that it is the Ubuntu that "should" control the power of the server.
Other settings are: HP Dynimic, HP Static Low Power and HP High Power.

I do not know where in the Ubuntu I can control this behaviour.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The hpvsa driver is no longer supported after 14.04. Your 16.04 uses the standard driver, which then leads to higher fan speed (~13% vs ~6% with hpvsa).